# How to let my html a tag run the function before go in to the page?

Tags: php

I was doing a function which is checking 2 user have a direct message room or no if they dun have will be insert a new direct message room if they have will go to room they chat before

here is my code

```
<a href="directMessageRoom.php">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-directmessage">Message</button>
    <?php
    include '../config.php';

    $target = $_GET['user'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    $targetusername = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$target' ")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $username=  mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $dm_sql="SELECT * FROM direct_message_room WHERE user_1_id ='$id' AND user_2_id='$target'";
    $check_direct_message_room = mysqli_query($connection, $dm_sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $check=  mysqli_num_rows($check_direct_message_room);

    if($check == 0){

    $direct_message_room_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection); 
    $direct_message_room_name ="INSERT INTO direct_message_room(`id`,`direct_message_room_name`,`user_1_id`,`user_2_id`) VALUES ('$direct_message_room_id ','test1','$id','$target')";

    $newDirectMessageRoom = mysqli_query($connection,$direct_message_room_name)or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    }

    else{

        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($check_direct_message_room)){
             echo '<a  href="directMessageRoom.php?directMessageRoomID='.$rowr3['id'].'></a>';
        }                        
    } 

    ?>
</a>
```

how i let this all happen when i click the a tag go into the page?

**I have update the code**

Additional question how i pass the new id to my a tag?

is this correct? `'CONCAT('$username','$targetusername')'`

i have error in line 47

```
 echo '<a  href="directMessageRoom.php?directMessageRoomID='.$rowr3['id'].'></a>';
```

the error is `Notice: Undefined variable: rowr3 in E:\Software\Xampp\htdocs\pme\main\user.php on line 47`

Comment: You're never fetching the rows from `$targetusername` and `$username`. And MySQL doesn't use `+` to concatenate strings, it uses `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Why are you calling `mysqli_fetch_array($check_direct_message_room)` when `$check == 0`?

Comment: `if($check = 0)` should be `if($check == 0)`. `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparing.

Comment: Are you insert the new room, you can use `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the ID that was assigned to it. I think that's the main thing you needed to know.\

Comment: i still new in php a lot of thing i still no sure how to do

Comment: `$new_room_id = mysqli_insert_id();`.

Comment: @Barmar can help me check my new update?

Comment: The error is because you use `$rowr3` instead of `$row3`. That should be obvious if you read the message carefully.

Comment: You need to call `mysqli_insert_id()` **after** you call `mysqli_query()`. How can it know the ID of the row that was inserted before you do the insert?

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. You should use prepared queries to prevent SQL injection.
2. You need to fetch the results from the first two queries.
3. You need to call `mysqli_insert_id()` **after** you do the `INSERT`, since it returns the ID assigned to the last row that was inserted.

   Message

   ```
   $target = $_GET['user'];
   $id = $_SESSION['id'];

   $target_stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id=?")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($target_stmt, "i", $target);
   mysqli_execute($target_stmt);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($target_stmt, $targetusername);
   mysqli_stmt_fetch($target_stmt);

   $username_stmt=  mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id=?") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($username_stmt, "i", $id);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($username_stmt);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($username_stmt, $username);
   mysqli_stmt_fetch($username_stmt);

   $dm_stmt=mysqli_prepare("SELECT id FROM direct_message_room WHERE user_1_id = ? AND user_2_id= ?") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($dm_stmt, "ii", $id, $target);
   mysql_stmt_execute($dm_stmt);
   mysql_stmt_store_result($dm_stmt);
   $check=  mysqli_stmt_num_rows($dm_stmt);

   if($check == 0){

       $insert_stmt = mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO direct_message_room(`direct_message_room_name`,`user_1_id`,`user_2_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
       $room_name = $username . $targetusername;
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert_stmt, "sii", $room_name, $id, $target);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($insert_stmt);
       $direct_message_room_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection); 
       echo '<a  href="directMessageRoom.php?directMessageRoomID='.$direct_message_room_id.'></a>';
   }

   else{
       mysqli_stmt_bind_result($dm_stmt, $room_id);
       while($row3 = mysqli_stmt_fetch($dm_stmt)){
           echo '<a  href="directMessageRoom.php?directMessageRoomID='.$room_id.'></a>';
       }                        
   } 

   ?>
   ```